# Mod_security won't block countries other than

Tags: apache, mod-security2, geoip2

I have Apache configured with mod_security and GeoIP2. GeoLite2-Country.mmdb is being downloaded by `geoipupdate` triggered by cron every week. My `/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf` configuration looks like:

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecRule ARGS:modsecparam "@contains test" "id:4321,deny,status:403,msg:'ModSecurity test rule has triggered'"

SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:20000,deny,status:403,msg:'NON PL IP addresses'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "!@streq PL"
...
```

my `/etc/modsecurity/crs-setup.conf` points to GeoIP db:

```
SecGeoLookupDB /etc/modsecurity/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
```

Running curl from my local machine: `curl 'https://host/login/index.html?modsecparam=test'`
leaves the trace in the log:

```
...
SecRule "TX:EXECUTING_PARANOIA_LEVEL" "@lt 2" "phase:1,auditlog,id:980013,nolog,skipAfter:END-RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION"

SecRule "ARGS:modsecparam" "@contains test" "phase:2,log,auditlog,id:4321,deny,status:403,msg:'ModSecurity test rule has triggered'"

SecRule "&TX:dos_burst_time_slice" "@eq 0" "phase:5,auditlog,id:912110,t:none,nolog,ver:OWASP_CRS/3.2.0,chain,skipAfter:END-DOS-PROTECTION-CHECKS"
SecRule "&TX:dos_counter_threshold" "@eq 0" "chain"
SecRule "&TX:dos_block_timeout" "@eq 0"
...
```

However from some reason it won't block countries other than PL. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the ask but the content after the "leaves the trace in the log" is not the log content, they are rules. Can you show us the debug.log content?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [crs-setup.conf](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/81782e955e6e7cfeea8cf1fa4c72238bc31401ef/crs-setup.conf.example#L649) example, where we explain depending on which version you are using, the file type you should use for geodb.

Probably the core is:

```
# There are two formats for the GeoIP database. ModSecurity v2 uses GeoLite (.dat files),
# and ModSecurity v3 uses GeoLite2 (.mmdb files).
...
# Therefore, if you use ModSecurity v2, you need to regenerate updated .dat files
# from CSV files first.
#
# You can achieve this using https://github.com/sherpya/geolite2legacy
# Pick the zip files from maxmind site:
# https://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country-CSV.zip
#
# Follow the guidelines for installing the tool and run:
# ./geolite2legacy.py -i GeoLite2-Country-CSV.zip \
#                     -f geoname2fips.csv -o /usr/share/GeoliteCountry.dat
```

As you mentioned apache, probably you need .dat files.

Felipe.
ModSecurity Dev-on-duty project